# PopUp Shopping Basket is overlaying my top header

Tags: wordpress, datastax-astra

When i scroll page a little bit down and check shopping basket my top header hides under top header and cant click X to turn off or even see shooping basket on the top, adding image how it looks like, [www.veedo.lt](http://www.veedo.lt)
https://ibb.co/K7Hw1hp

i cant edit in customizer or elementor, i think because it popups need to be edited in files.